# Null check operator used on a null value when logout using getX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-getx

So, everything was going well when login but a `_CastError` was thrown when logout even tho the logout was going fine but I am concerned about this error making a problem in production mode.

this is the code from my **auth_model**

```
Rxn<User> _user = Rxn<User>() ;


 String? get user => _user.value!.email;

 @override
 void onInit() {
  // TODO: implement onInit
   super.onInit();
   _user.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
  }
```

and this is the code from my **controller_view**

```
 return Obx((){
  return(Get.find<AuthViewModel>().user != null)
      ? HomeScreen()
      : Home();
});
```

and this one is from my **homeScreen**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Home Screen",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: TextButton(
              child: Text(
                  "logout"
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Get.offAll(Home());
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'll appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: the question is understandable, please provide some more relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem.

```dart
/// You tried to declare a private variable that might be `null`.
/// All `Rxn` will be null by default.
Rxn<User> _user = Rxn<User>();

/// You wanted to get a String from `email` property... from that variable.
/// But you also want to return `null` if it doesn't exist. see: `String?` at the beginning.
/// But you also tell dart that it never be null. see: `_user.value!`.
String? get user => _user.value!.email;

/// That line above will convert to this.
String? get user => null!.email;
```

You are marking a `null` as `not-null` by adding a `!` before the next operand. That is why you get the error. To fix that, use `?` instead of `!`.

```dart
/// This will return `null` and ignore the next `.email` operand
/// if `_user.value` is `null`.
String? get user => _user.value?.email;
```

Comment: thank you so much, this null check is confusing me whenever i'm writing code, flutter keep yelling at me to put a null check operator so i was just following flutter errors fixes.

Comment: Yah, it was confusing at first... Just remember that when you want to have an object that is possibly `null` and you also want to access the property inside of it, use `?` ... Only use `!` when you know the object will always be there and never gonna be `null`. If you know when to use them, you'll be fine.. Null safety is cool! :)